# Can't create a pull request to merge a feature branch into a master branch in a newly created repository

Tags: git, github

I created a new repository locally, and pushed it to Github, following https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

1. On my local machine, I created  a new repository, and a feature branch, by

   ```
   git init
   git checkout -b featurebranch
   git add somefile
   git commit -m
   ```

   Then on github website, I created a repository.

   Back on my local machine,

   ```
   git remote add origin remote-repository-URL

   git push origin featurebranch
   ```
2. Then I realized that I needed to create a master branch, so that
   later I can create a pull request to someone else to merge the
   feature branch into the master branch. So I create a master branch

   ```
   git checkout -b master
   ```

   `git status` shows the working directory is clean, so I pushed the
   master branch to Github

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

   On Github, I set the default branch to be the master branch, but 
   couldn't create a pull request to merge the feature branch to the
   master branch with the following notification:

   > **Comparing changes**
   >
   > There isn’t anything to compare. master is up to date with all commits
   >   from B02913. Try switching the base for your comparison.
3. I thought the message was telling me the reason was that the commits
   on the master and feature branches are the same, so I went back to
   my local repository, i removed everything from the master branch,
   and pushed the empty commit on the master branch to Github again, by

   ```
   git rm somefile
   git commit -m 
   git push origin master
   ```

   Even though the current commit on the master branch, I still
   couldn't create a pull request to merge the feature branch to the
   master branch, with the same notification as above.

   I don't understand why I still get the same notification, because
   now the current commit on master is empty, while the current commit
   on the feature branch isn't.

Now how can I do, to create a pull request to merge the feature branch into the master branch?

Thanks.

Comment: You created a feature branch, then created master based on this branch, then added a commit on master. So the feature branch is already merged to master: you created master from that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I realized that I needed to create a master branch, so that later I can create a pull request to someone else to merge the feature branch into the master branch.

This is totally wrong. `master` is just an arbitrary name that happens to be the conventional default but at no means is mandatory in any way. You can create pull requests for any branch to be merged in any other branch.

This requires of course that there **is** something to merge. In your case, the feature branch is already completely part of the master branch, so there is nothing to merge. Create another commit on your feature branch and you can create a pull request. Or as you created a new commit on the master branch you can also already create a pull request to merge the master branch into the feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge **that** branch into master (as master already contains all the commits from that branch), but you will be able to merge further branches that you branch off the master.